# Fit text into a fixed-width column after pressing a button

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I have text in a text box that I want to format to a fixed-width column of between 30 and 60 characters. The user will be allowed to specify how wide each line should be (i.e. the width of the column) but it will default to 50 characters.

I have done some research however, I couldn't find anything of what my goal is.
I have tried `String.Format` however, it doesn't do anything

```
string test = ""
        if(txtBoxContent.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There are no '>' symbols to remove. Please paste the infected text first");
        }

        else if (!txtBoxContent.Text.Contains(">"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There are no '>' symbol(s) in the text OR are already removed");
        }

        else
        {
            contentWithoutCharacters = txtBoxContent.Text.Replace(">", "");
            txtBoxContent.Text = contentWithoutCharacters;


            //MessageBox.Show("Removed Successfully");

            test = string.Format("{0,50}", contentWithoutCharacters); // this
        }

    }
```

I am assume I am taking the wrong approach or not using the `string.format` correctly. Any guidance will be appreciated

Update:
I think i didn't explain my self clearly.

For example: the below text is a original text

> I have text in a text box that I want to format to a fixed-width column of between 30 and 60 characters. The user will be allowed to specify how wide each line should be (i.e. the width of the column) but it will default to 50 characters.

when i press a button, i want the above text to display 50 characters on each line

> I have text in a text box that I want to format to a fixed-width **new line** 
>   column of between 30 and 60 characters. The user will be allowed to specify how **new line** wide each line should be (i.e. the width of the column) but it will default to 50 characters.

Hope it makes more sense now

Comment: I don't seem to understand your question, but is `string.PadRight(int)` what you're looking for?

Comment: Did you use a fixed-width font for your textbox? In variable-width fonts each letter has a different width and spaces are smaller than _w_

Comment: That snippet is so inadequate that it get to be very hard to guess what you want to accomplish.  Randomly: how much text fits depends on the font size, not the number of characters, use TextRenderer.MeasureText().

Comment: @someone that's not working. What i mean is each line should have a default of 50 characters unless user changes the number itself

Comment: @Steve I don't know. How can I find that out?

Comment: Your string.Format does what you have asked it to do. It add the character space in front of whatever you have in your textbox unless the content is already 50 or more characters. At the end the string _test_ has a length of 50. You can check the length using the debugger. However, the display (the alignment) of that string depends on the font used to display it

Comment: Why -1 ????????

Comment: WHY  -1 FOR THIS QUESTION. I NEED EXPLANATION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're determined to break your string up into *n*-width pieces, here's an approach. However, you'll soon see that the string gets broken up in ways you may not want...which is why you're getting comments wondering whay you want to do this.

```
  var originalText = "Now is the time; yada yada; thing and the thing! Now is the time; yada yada; thing and the thing! Now is the time; yada yada; thing and the thing! Now is the time; yada yada; thing and the thing! Now is the time; yada yada; thing and the thing! Now is the time; yada yada; thing and the thing! Now is the time; yada yada; thing and the thing! ";

  txtBoxContent.Clear();
  txtBoxContent.WordWrap = false; //--> to make sure nothing spills to the next line
  var part = string.Empty;

  var index = 0; //--> define this outside the loop, so you can use it to pick up any remainder
  var width = 30;  //--> ...or whatever width you need

  for ( index = 0; index < ( originalText.Length - width ); index += width )
  {
    part = originalText.Substring( index, width );
    //--> do something useful with the fixed-length part...
    txtBoxContent.Append( part + Environment.NewLine );
  }

  //--> deal with the remainder, if any...
  if ( index < originalText.Length )
  {
    //--> the last piece...it will be less than width wide...
    part = originalText.Substring( index, originalText.Length - index );
    txtBoxContent.Append( part );
  }
```

...and here's what you get:

```
Now is the time; yada yada; th
ing and the thing! Now is the
time; yada yada; thing and the
 thing! Now is the time; yada
yada; thing and the thing! Now
 is the time; yada yada; thing
 and the thing! Now is the tim
e; yada yada; thing and the th
ing! Now is the time; yada yad
a; thing and the thing! Now is
 the time; yada yada; thing an
d the thing!
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works1 just one question. If they say width should be 50 charactors, i should put 49(in computing it starts with 0)?

Comment: No, the width variable should be what they say...the `SubString` takes a width as a second argument, and the loop will do the math. The *only* thing you need to change is the value of `width`.

Comment: Also notice...if you want *n* characters to display, you don't count the `Environment.NewLine`...which may be 1 character or 2...but either way, it doesn't contribute to the width of the displayed characters.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. One last question, will this code work if I need `minWIdth =30` and `maxwidth=60` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use padleft or padright methods according to your need. Here is the example of padright method:

```
string str  = "HelloWorld"
str.PadRight(11);
```

Output = 'HelloWorld '

Here is the example of padleft method:

```
string str  = "HelloWorld"
str.PadLeft(11);
```

Output = ' HelloWorld'

Comment: padleft consumes all charatcers and then leave the remaining number of characters as blank spaces at the left similarly padright consumes all charatcers and then leave the remaining number of characters as blank spaces at the right.

Comment: It doesn't seem to effect anything

Comment: you should use the number in str.PadRight(number) acording to your need ... say you entered a string "Hello" whose size is 5 but you want that it should be considered as 50 so use this line str.PadRight(50); and it will add 45 spaces after "Hello" and consider it a string of 50 length.